# Using Converse Js, Can not Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: xmpp

I am working on converseJS, and there are some error message on chrome debug console.
Here is the error:

`"url:7070 Origin url:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."`

Is there any good ideas to resolve this.

Thanks you

Xin

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting cross-domain request restrictions in Javascript.

Most browsers support [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) nowadays (which is the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header mentioned in your error message). Enabling and configuring CORS depends on your XMPP server or BOSH connection manager that you are using.

An alternative approach that will work with any browser is to proxy requests through your web server, which depends purely on your web server.

Here are some useful links for further reading:

- [BOSH: Cross Domain Issues](http://prosody.im/doc/setting_up_bosh#cross-domain_issues) (documentation from the [Prosody](https://prosody.im/) project)
- [Cross-Domain AJAX for XMPP HTTP Binding Made Easy](http://metajack.im/2010/01/19/crossdomain-ajax-for-xmpp-http-binding-made-easy/) (blog post by the [strophe.js](http://strophe.im/strophejs/) author)